# Get 'Nan' when auto calculate

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-events

I am creating a form using Gridview in ASP.NET.  When the user fills in Qty and Price it needs to automatically calculate the Total.  However, my Total always returns Nan (Not a number).  What am I doing wrong?

The ASP page looks like this:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
 AutoGenerateColumns="false">
         <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Item" HeaderText="Item" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Item_Desc" ItemStyle-CssClass="price" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Jumlahdatang" >
                 <ItemTemplate  >
                      <asp:TextBox ID="Qty" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox> 
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Harga Satuan" >
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="price" runat="server"    ></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate> 
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Harga Total"  >
                 <ItemTemplate >
                     <asp:Label ID="total" runat="server" Text="0" ></asp:Label>

                 </ItemTemplate>

              </asp:TemplateField>
         </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

The JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // give value 0 first time 
     $(function() {
         $("[id*=Qty]").val("0");
         $("[id*=price]").val("0");
         $("[id*=total1]").val("0");
     });
 //check data must number on Qty
     $("[id*=Qty]").live("change", function() {
         if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
             $(this).val('0');
         } else {
             $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()).toString());
         }
     });
  //check data must number on price
     $("[id*=price]").live("change", function() {
         if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
             $(this).val('0');
         } else {
             $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()).toString());
         }
     });

     $("[id*=price]").live("keyup", function() {
         if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
             if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
                 var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                 $("[id*=total]", row).html(parseFloat($(".Qty", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val()));
             }
         } else {
             $(this).val('');
         }

     });
```

Comment: This can happen if you've got a value in one of your fields that can't be parsed as an integer.

Comment: adding quotes (single or double) javascript will read the value as a string. I would remove the quotes in your input values.

Comment: Maybe you have comma as decimal separator in your inputs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i input integer type value (1,2,3,4) and it return nan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))) {
```

why are you using isNan and parseInt at the same time ?

i think is should be :

```
if (isNaN($(this).val()))
```

which returns true if val = string and false if number

another one.. you only need to parseInt if you will use their value in a formula ..

Comment: It for convertting when is not a number then become 0.you can try input a charater so it became 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is your purified code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// give value 0 first time 
 $(function() {
     $("[id*=Qty]").val(0);
     $("[id*=price]").val(0);
     $("[id*=total1]").val(0);
 });
//check data must number on Qty
 $("[id*=Qty]").live("change", function() {
     if (isNaN($(this).val())) {
         $(this).val(0);
     }
 });
 //check data must number on price
 $("[id*=price]").live("change", function() {
     if (isNaN($(this).val())) {
         $(this).val(0);
     }
 });

 $("[id*=price]").live("keyup", function() {
     var row = $(this).closest("tr");
     $("[id*=total]", row).html(parseFloat($(".Qty", row).val()) * parseFloat($(this).val()));
 });
```